# How to read/write parquet files in google drive and share them

Tags: python, pandas, google-drive-api

i would like to read/write parquet file ie read it and write it (and continue to share it) on google drive.
I know how to read them. I have written a function to do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import BytesIO

def load_google_file(code):
    url = f"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={code}"
    file = requests.get(url)
    bytesio = BytesIO(file.content)
    return pd.read_parquet(bytesio)
```

but how to update this file from python and continue to share it on google drive with the same code ?